# Trouble with emacs when loading files

Tags: emacs

My emacs starts quickly : 1-2sec to load yasnippets but I have no problem with that.
Actually when i want to open a file Emacs can take like 1-2 minutes to open it. It has begun today and I don't know how to fix it, this is really annoying. When I cancel the openning I can see `[yas] Loading snippet files from /home/MYNAME/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20160226.1359/snippets/cc-mode`

Also, when I start emacs with `emacs -q` then I can open files immedialy with `neotree` or `C-x C-f`

Any tips ?

Comment: Open Emacs with no init file (`emacs -q`) and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah sorry I just see that and I tried it, the problem is fixed when I do that but I lost all my saves options, so I'm not able to use packages anymore :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the emacs init file, the `auto-complete-c-headers` package seems to be the problem. When I delete theses lines :

```
    (defun my:ac-c-header-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"usr/include/c++/5.2.1")
)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
```

The problem is solved : i replaced by the code as follows:

```
    (add-hook 'c++-mode-common-hook
      (lambda()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/include/c++/5.2.1")))
```